# cannot execute unlisten during recovery

Tags: npgsql

I'm getting the error "cannot execute unlisten during recovery" when I use Pooling=True in my connection string.

This error is on a replicated / read server which is running on hot standby.

Answer (score 3):

This is still happening with version 3.2.7. It should be possible to run SELECT queries on a hot standby database, but when doing this with Npgsql, we get

```
PostgresException 25006: cannot execute UNLISTEN during recovery    
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<DoReadMessage>d__157.MoveNext()
```

A look at [the source](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/c67a1f4fe4fd935a2606f6166bb7a64fde866331/src/Npgsql/NpgsqlConnector.cs) confirms that, when pooling connections, Npgsql cleans up after each connection is closed. One of the cleanup operations is `UNLISTEN *`, which fails on hot standby databases, since it affects state.

Fortunately, there are [connection string parameters](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html#performance) we can set to avoid this. As the original question mentions, you can disable connection pooling. However, in situations where performance is important, it is better to add `No Reset On Close=true;` to the connection string instead.

Using `No Reset On Close` does carry some risk of leaking state from one command to the next, but since you're in read-only mode, it can't affect your stored data. Be careful to dispose of cursors, sequences and temporary tables  if you're using them. On the bright side, it may give your queries a slight speed boost.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, was pulling my hair about this when my read replica responded with 25006!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be documented in [the PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hot-standby.html): a hot standby can't do LISTEN/UNLISTEN/NOTIFY.